# perl packaging dbd mysql module in script

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, cpan, dbd

I have a script and keep all external modules local so I can then package my entire script in a zip and have it work on all machines without having to install all the modules on different machines.
I do:

```
use lib "$Bin/cpan";
```

I am trying to initiate a connection to a mysql database so I need to install DBD, DBI and mysql locally how can I do this? I tried the same way by copying the .pm files and it either gives me

```
DBD::mysql initialisation failed: Can't locate object method "driver" via package "DBD::mysql" at C:/Perl/lib/DBI.pm line 815.
```

or

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC
```

Comment: Are you also copying the `DBD::mysql` libraries (`DBD/mysql/mysql.so` or `DBD/mysql/mysql.dll`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply transferring archives will probably not work, especially if you're transferring across operating systems or architectures (aside from simply missing files). I recommend using [Carton](https://metacpan.org/module/carton) to automate dependency management. Under the hood it uses [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) (a brilliant module for dev and deployment in its own right) and [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3acpanminus) to get the work done.